# What are ALMs, LEs and ALUTs?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, intel-fpga, computer-architecture, terminology

Does ALM mean "Adaptive logic module"?

[www.altera.com/literature/ds/ds_nios2_perf.pdf‎](http://www.altera.com/literature/ds/ds_nios2_perf.pdf%E2%80%8E)
Jul 1, 2013 -

> One ALUT is equivalent to about 1.25 LEs.

Does LE mean logic element and ALUT means adaptive look-up table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://quartushelp.altera.com/10.0/mergedProjects/reference/glossary/def_alm.htm

> The Adaptive Logic Module (ALM) is the basic building block of
>   supported device families and is designed to maximize performance and
>   resource usage. Each ALM, composed of two Adaptive Look-Up Tables
>   (ALUT) ...

LE has meant "logic element" for many years, although what defines a logic element is not entirely static, in Altera-land is usually means a 4-input look-up table (sometimes called a 4-LUT) + a d-type flipflop (DFF).

Comment: Do you have a reference for the Altera definition of the logic element?

Comment: Not a good one... This is as close as I got, but it looks out of date (Xilinx's devices stop at Spartan 2 in the table!): http://www.altera.co.uk/cgi-bin/device_compare.pl - it says `Altera's and Xilinx's basic building block is a 4-input look-up table (LUT), a flip-flop and some additional circuitry that Altera calls a logic element (LE) and Xilinx calls a logic cell (LC). `